# Filter the output of powercli command to only had a part of it

Tags: bash, powershell, awk, sed, powercli

The output of the command is:

```
PS /root> Get-VM -Name alex-deploy2-000638 | Get-Harddisk

CapacityGB      Persistence                                                    Filename
----------      -----------                                                    --------
60.000          Persistent           …1] alex-deploy2-000638/alex-deploy2-000638_2.vmdk
```

I need to always have the last part after the /

```
alex-deploy2-000638_2.vmdk
```

Is there a way to filter that output to cut everything else that is not disk-name.vmdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select the property you are interested in (eg: `FileName`).
Then, you can use `Split-Path -Leaf` to get the filename without the folder.

Since your `Get-HardDisk` command can return multiple disks, I included a `Foreach` for the last part, to make sure it work with a single disk and multiple disks.

```
(Get-VM -Name alex-deploy2-000638 | Get-Harddisk).FileName  | % {$_ | Split-Path -Leaf}
```